# what is the use of SITE_ID settings in django?

Tags: django, django-sites

When I am doing the flatpage tutorial, I was getting error for `SITE_ID` not being set. I inserted `SITE_ID=1` in the settings file and everything worked fine. But I don't know what this actually means.

I read through the `django docs`. but I am not totally clear what its use.
when will I use something like SITE_ID=2.

On the same note, I used the following snippet in my code without actually knowing what it does:

```
current_site=Site.objects.get_current()
```

I assume this has something to do with `SITE_ID` but may be not.

Some example to demonstrate where `SITE_ID` could take different values than 1 would help.

Answer (score 6):

It is helpful is you use your code on multiple sites, or if you share a database with another site. An example from [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from django.contrib.sites.managers import CurrentSiteManager

class Photo(models.Model):
    photo = models.FileField(upload_to='/home/photos')
    photographer_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site)
    objects = models.Manager()
    on_site = CurrentSiteManager()
```

With this model, `Photo.objects.all()` will return all Photo objects in the database, but `Photo.on_site.all()` will return only the Photo objects associated with the current site, according to the SITE_ID setting.

Put another way, these two statements are equivalent:

```
Photo.objects.filter(site=settings.SITE_ID)
Photo.on_site.all()
```

Comment: how do you set which SITE_ID corresponds to which site. for ex `1` corresponds to `example.com`, `2` corresponds to `tutorial.com` etc

Comment: @brainstorm Each site would likely have their own `settings.py` where it would be set.

Answer (score 0):

[From documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#site-id):

SITE_ID
Default: Not defined

The ID, as an integer, of the current site in the django_site database table. This is used so that application data can hook into specific sites and a single database can manage content for multiple sites.